# How can I scale object on one side only with a speed factor?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScaleOneSide : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1;

    float mfX;
    float mfY;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        mfX = transform.position.x - transform.localScale.x / 2.0f;
        mfY = transform.position.y - transform.localScale.y / 2.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            Vector3 v3Scale = transform.localScale;
            //transform.localScale = new Vector3(v3Scale.x + 0.1f, v3Scale.y + 0.1f, v3Scale.z);
            //transform.position = new Vector3(mfX + transform.localScale.x / 2.0f, mfY + transform.localScale.y / 2.0f, 0);

            //transform.localScale = new Vector3(v3Scale.x + 0.1f, v3Scale.y, v3Scale.z);
            transform.position = new Vector3(mfX + transform.localScale.x / 2.0f, 0, 0);

            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(transform.localScale, new Vector3(v3Scale.x + 0.1f,0,0), speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

When using only this two lines it was working fine without changing the speed:

```
 //transform.localScale = new Vector3(v3Scale.x + 0.1f, v3Scale.y + 0.1f, v3Scale.z);
   //transform.position = new Vector3(mfX + transform.localScale.x / 2.0f, mfY + transform.localScale.y / 2.0f, 0);
```

But now I'm trying to add to the scaling a speed.
I want when I press the mouse left button it will scale the object according to the speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are familiarized with **Coroutines** you could try handing the scaling there.

Why? well since using **Lerp** with the parameter time t as a speed that may be constant and a **deltaTime** that just references the change of time between frames will give you most of the times values in one range, so you may see come jiggering there. That is because **Lerp**, as any interpolation function, receives a normalized property t that goes between 0.0 and 1.0, where 0.0 is your initial value, and 1.0 is the desired value.

You have already the data you need, you just need to put it in a coroutine, like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScaleOneSide : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1f;

    float mfX;
    float mfY;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        mfX = transform.position.x - transform.localScale.x / 2.0f;
        mfY = transform.position.y - transform.localScale.y / 2.0f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            StartCoroutine(Scale(new Vector3(v3Scale.x + 0.1f, 0f, 0f)));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Scale(Vector3 _newScale)
    {
        float n = 0.0f;
        Vector3 originalScale = transform.localScale; // It is important to have your scale reference before interpolating.

        while(n < 1.0f)
        {
            transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(originalScale, _newScale, n);
            n += Time.deltaTime / speed; // here your normalized t will increment from 0 to 1.
            yield return null;
        }

        transform.localScale = Vector3.Lerp(originalScale, _newScale, 1.0f); // Just to make sure it scales to the destiny point, since n doesn't always reach 1.
    }
}
```

You can also do this with update, but it gives you less code handling, in my personal experience, since it is best to separate functionality when possible.

Comment: You probably want to use GetButtonDown instead of GetButton, so you start the Coroutine only once, rather than multiple times if the button is held for more than a frame.

Comment: I just copy-pasted the user's code, but yes.